# Input signal for Tasker on an external network

Tags: android, tasker

I have a standard Android smartphone connected to 4G (yes it can connect to my house's WIFI but the point of this question is to work from outside).

I would like to trigger a task on demand for an external source (website click on my server, mail, iCal event, opened door) onto a [Tasker task](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm).

> Sidenote : Tasker works with a profile / task system : a profile is when an event occurs (date, phone event,...), then several tasks can be bound to this profile as start and end tasks.

The particular test case is : "When I click on 'I'm on vacation' on my server's webpage, it should send something to my phone to switch a 'Vacation' variable on tasker" (yes my phone is nearby but I am THAT lazy ;))

I known that there are already some alternatives like

- Pushbullet => 3rd party app
- (G)Mail => the better but might be overkill
- SMS => needs a SMS sender
- Periodic HTTP GET => I want immediate, too periodic GET might drain battery

I would like to know if there is a "simple" solution, preferably without a 3rd party and I would like to keep the task bound to a simple profile, not multi-profile like "hey a mail","hey a sms",...

Reminder :

- External 4G network (but I can forward ports)
- Immediate action (let's say 10s latency is acceptable)
- I already use Tasker for other things so I would like to avoid depending on other services/apps such as IFTTT or Trigger for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pushbullet has a Tasker plugin embedded with the android application which allows to filter incoming messages and (regex) parse text within.

A program can for example

- push a pushbullet via pushbullet's api
- on the phone a tasker profile can intercept the incoming message and regex match the message with a known patern (I'm on vacation, Intrusion,...)
- and the phone could trigger a task accordingly (notify, ring,...)